# Mockito DAO interface from service impl

Tags: spring, mockito

I'm using Mockito for testing my API Service REST, i'm using Spring Framework 4.1.4.RELEASE and Mockito 1.9.5.

I have a multi-brand system for access to unique DAOImpl (With unique for each brand @PersistenceContext(unitname = "emX"), where "X" it's brand char) , each brand extends from abstract DaoBase class (who implemements an interface called Dao) and i access from Service class obtaining the component via:

applicationContext.getBean(qualifier.concat(brand.name()), clazz)

(Where qualifier.concat(brand.name()) its = "DaoA" for example)

This is the structure:

> - es.app.service
>
>   > - ServiceClass.java calls DaoFactory to get Impl.
> - es.app.dao
>
>   > - Dao.java
>   > - DaoBase.java implements Dao
>   > - DaoFactory.java
> - es.app.dao.impl
>
>   > - DaoAImpl.java extends DaoBase @Repository("DaoA")
>   > - DaoBImpl.java extends DaoBase @Repository("DaoB")
>   > - DaoCImpl.java extends DaoBase @Repository("DaoC")
>   > - DaoDImpl.java extends DaoBase @Repository("DaoD")

Then i have a test class on Test Packages

> - es.app.service
>
>   > ServiceClassTest.java

I put a little code for each class here:

> DaoFactory.java

```
@Component
public class DaoFactory implements Serializable, ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext  ctx;
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    private static final Logger LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DaoFactory.class);

    public Dao getInstance(GroupBrand brand){
        switch(brand){
            case A:
            case B:
            case C:
            case D:
                return (Dao)getComponent("Dao",Dao.class, brand);
            default: break;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported brand ".concat(brand.name()));
    }

    private Object getComponent(String qualifier, Class<?> clazz, GroupBrand brand){
        Object instance = ctx.getBean(qualifier.concat(brand.name()), clazz);
        if(Utils.isNull(instance)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unkown business bean with Qualifier:  ".concat(qualifier.concat(brand.name())).concat("type: ").concat(clazz.getName()));
        }
        LOGGER.debug("DAO retrived: " + qualifier.concat(brand.name()) +" class: " + clazz.getName());
        return instance;
    }


    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = applicationContext;
    }


}
```

> DaoBase.java

```
public abstract class DaoBase implements Dao {


    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
    private static final String EMPTY = "";
    private static final Logger     LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DaoBase.class);

    @Override
    public Boolean findAvailability(GroupBrand marca, String code) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Conn.isAvailability");
        query.setParameter(1, code);
        query.setParameter(2, marca.toCharCode());
        try{
            String value = (String)query.getSingleResult();
                        if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            return false;
                        }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }

}
```

> DaoAImpl.java

```
@Repository("DaoA")
public class DaoAImpl extends DaoBase {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "emA")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional("A")
    public Boolean findAvailability(GroupBrand marca, String code) {
        return super.findAvailability(marca, code);
    }
}
```

> ServiceClass.java

```
    @Override
    public boolean isAvailable(GroupBrand brand, String code){
        Boolean available = getDMSQisAvailability(brand, code);
        return available;
    }

    protected Boolean isAvailability(GroupBrand marca, String kvps){
        boolean value = daoFactory.getInstance(marca).findDMSQisAvailability(marca, code);
        return value;
    }
```

> ServiceClassTest.java

```
    @InjectMocks
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("serviceClass")
        private ServiceClass srv;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("DaoFactory")
    protected DaoFactory daoFactory;

    @Mock
    protected Dao dao;

    @Override
    public void mockBehaivors() throws ResourceException, ResourceNotFoundException, ApiException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        dao = daoFactory.getInstance(marca);

        when(dao.findAvailability(any(GroupBrand.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);

    }

    @Test
        public void isAvailableTest() throws ResourceException, Exception{
            Boolean available = srv.isAvailable(GroupBrand.A, "CODE");
        }
```

I need to coverage ServiceClass.java class but i can't mock Dao calls from this Test class always do real call and don't return what i defined on "when", other tests works but are not using dao access.

Anyone can help me?

(Apologies for my poor english)..

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried the below solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least i found a solution of my problem,

I haved to mock **DaoFactory** when calls **getInstance()** i return a mock of **Dao** class.

Class test it like this:

```
@InjectMocks
@Autowired
@Qualifier("serviceClass")
private ServiceClass srv;

@Mock
@Autowired
@Qualifier("DaoA")
protected Dao dao;

@Mock
@Autowired
@Qualifier("DaoFactory")
protected DaoFactory daoFactory;

@Override
public void mockBehaivors() throws ResourceException, ResourceNotFoundException, ApiException {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    when(daoFactory.getInstance(GroupBrand.A)).thenReturn(dao);

    when(dao.findAvailability(any(GroupBrand.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);

}

@Test
    public void isAvailableTest() throws ResourceException, Exception{
        Boolean available = srv.isAvailable(GroupBrand.A, "CODE");
    }
```

And it's works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using  @MockBean(Ideally @Mock also same) on DAO and doing stubbing as mentioned below.
Annotate @Before on the test case initialization method and move when clause logic to actual test case(I always do like that)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest extends MyServiceImpl {



    @Autowired
    private MyService myervice;

    @MockBean
    private MyDAO myDao;

    @Before
    public void setupMock()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```

> can you try creating stub for not to call DAO  as in below snippet in
>   the test case.In your example you have done it in the test
>   initialization block

```
     AddressDTO planContactaddressDTO = buildAddressDTO();
   //build this stub method buildAddressDTO() to return AddressDTO which your actual DAO will return
   when(myDao.saveAddress(addressBO)).thenReturn(addressDTO);
```

Comment: Hi, i tried but it doesn't work, but thanks of this i found a solution!!

Comment: Cool,What is the fix you have made!